# Capturing mouse event data outside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

I am working on a Facebook app and have run into a situation where being able to capture whether or not the mouse has left the app's iframe would be really great info to have. I've tried playing with window.blur() and window.focus() in jquery but (for reasons regarding how my content renders at the moment) this only works in Firefox. I have considered using mousemove() to capture the x and y position of the mouse but it would appear that once the mouse leaves the iframe I'm out of luck.

tl;dr I have an iframe that I have control of and a page it's embedded into that I don't. I need to capture the mouse movement/click/whatever outside my iframe and want to know if that's actually possible. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using mouseenter and mouseleave on the body tag of the iframes document?

Comment: if the iframes content and the page outsides content doesn't have the same document.domain, you will never in a million years be abel to get any info about the mouse after it leaves the iframe. But the actual event of leaving should be doable.

Comment: @Martin and qwertymk. As FB generates the iframe, to the best of my knowledge, I don't believe I can call anything on it.

Comment: You don't need to work on the iframe itself, just the content you have inside of it - namely the document/document.body.

Comment: Facebook doesn't generate the iframe. The iframe is hosted from your server. It will behave exactly like any normal web page would behave inside an iframe.

Comment: @Nathan Interesting, I'll have to ask the person who set that part up, he had led me to believe otherwise.

@Martin and qwertymk Thank you very much! This was absolutely the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a combination of Martin and qwertymk's solution to the issue. I'd check you guys off as answering the question but since you can't approve of comments this will have to do. Thanks all.